# onWebsocketHandshakeReceivedAsClient with response: 101 for Spring boot Backend for Android app websocket STOMP

Tags: android, spring-boot, stomp

I've just learnt and implemented my first android websocket app with simple spring boot backend using STOMP :

```java
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
     registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
     registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").withSockJS();
}
```

and this is my android client implementation :

```java
mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "http://172.12.12.159:8600/chat/websocket");
mStompClient.connect();
mStompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(lifecycleEvent -> {
    switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {

        case OPENED:
            Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
            break;

        case ERROR:
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", lifecycleEvent.getException());
            break;

        case CLOSED:
            Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection closed");
            break;
    }
});
mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
    Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
});

mStompClient.send("/app/hello", "My first STOMP message!").subscribe();
```

Every-time I try to run this android client, I'm getting the following message.

```
2021-06-05 10:36:39.028 13391-13425/com.example.websocketokhttp D/WebSocketsConnectionProvider: onWebsocketHandshakeReceivedAsClient with response: 101 
2021-06-05 10:36:39.028 13391-13425/com.example.websocketokhttp D/WebSocketsConnectionProvider: onOpen with handshakeData: 101 
2021-06-05 10:36:39.035 13391-13425/com.example.websocketokhttp D/WebSocketsConnectionProvider: Emit lifecycle event: OPENED
2021-06-05 10:36:39.039 13391-13425/com.example.websocketokhttp D/LongOperation: Stomp connection opened
```

May be I'm missing a very common thing in the Spring boot server-side or android client ? as I
Please enlighten me in this regard..

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell these are just normal debug log messages. The first three are coming directly from [WebSocketsConnectionProvider](https://github.com/MobileDews/Android-Stomp-Over-Websocket/blob/6c1f8c93d5b0e721afcf0382d5303c93e5594323/stomplibrary/src/main/java/com/techdew/stomplibrary/WebSocketsConnectionProvider.java#L73) (i.e. the Android WebSocket client). The last message is coming from *your* application.

Regarding the `101` status, this is normal for WebSocket connections as the client will start with an HTTP handshake and then switch protocols to the WebSocket protocol. The `101` is the normal HTTP status for protocol switching. See more [here](https://evertpot.com/http/101-switching-protocols).